# Помогите решить задачу (python)

Tags: python

Вводится список в виде целых чисел в одну строку через пробел. С помощью цикла for необходимо найти наименьшее четное значение в этом списке. Полученный результат вывести на экран. Если четного значени нет, то вывести слово "None" (без кавычек).
Реализовать программу без использования функции min.
Пытался в одну строку не получается можно решать и не в одну строку.

```
print((list(i for i in map(int, input().split()) if i % 2 == 0 )))
```

Comment: Раз можно не в одну, то решайте не в одну.

Comment: А `sorted` можно использовать? ;)  Так то у вас почти готовое решение, только зачем-то лишние скобки и т.п.

Comment: в одну строку без `min` можно решить эту задачу с помощью функций `sorted` и `next`

Answer (score 0):

```py
a, *_ = sorted(filter(lambda x: not x % 2, map(int, input().split()))) or (None,)
print(a)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]